# Flutter: Realtime database, append data under specific UID

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add a grid on every click to real-time database. However, when a new value is added, although its key is different, still database replaces the old index with new one.

To summarise, this is my intended structure:

```
User.UID
|
|___ 0 -> cross
|
|___ 1 -> tick
|
|___ 2 -> cross
|
|___ 3 -> tick
```

But I'm getting:

```
User.UID
|
|___ 1 -> tick
```

i.e: Old index 0 is replaced with new index 1.

My code is:

```
playGame(int index, final databaseReference) {
    if (this.gameState[index] == "empty") {
      setState(() {
        if (this.isCross) {
          this.gameState[index] = "cross";
        } else {
          this.gameState[index] = "circle";
        }
        this.isCross = !this.isCross;
        this.checkWin();
      });

      databaseReference
          .child(authUser.currentUser.uid)
          .set({index.toString(): gameState[index]});
    }
```

Grid:

```
Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                color: Colors.white12,
                child: GridView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10.0),
                  itemCount: 9,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) => SizedBox(
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        this.playGame(i, databaseReference);
                      },
                      child: Image(
                        image: this.getImage(this.gameState[i]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Can anyone please help how can I fix this?

Comment: How is `playGame(int index` called?

Comment: Sorry for late response. playGame() is called whenever user clicks on the grid. Please review the code I added for the grid, where playGame() is called. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that. You'll have to do some debugging yourself though, as Stack Overflow is a highly inefficient interactive debugger. For example: when you `print(index)` in `playGame` does it have the value you expect? If so, if you put a breakpoint on the call to `set()` does it show the correct value for both `index` and `gameState[index]`?

Comment: I think I’m unable to describe my problem properly.  Issue is that for some reason firebase is overwriting the old values with new ones (even though their key is different). Still, I checked the index values and they are as expected. The index passed to playGame() is same as the one passed to set function. Thinking, I’m out of luck? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `set(...)` on a location, it **sets** the values you pass to that location, overwriting any existing value(s) at the location.

If you want to only update specific keys in the location, use the `update(...)` method. So in your case that'd me:

```
databaseReference
  .child(authUser.currentUser.uid)
  .update({index.toString(): gameState[index]});
```

Comment: Thank you so much man. This did the trick. I just need to fetch these attributes on other device when they get updated. Can you please point me towards a source? Wasn't able to find anything on firebase.google.com that will work in flutter unfortunately :(

Comment: For FlutterFire docs for Realtime Database and an example app, see https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database